# Not able to publish a message onto RabbitMQ using header exchange with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I have a very basic `Spring Boot` application that is publishing two messages to `RabbitMQ` using `headers` exchange. Both the `exchange` and `queue` is getting created but the message is not reaching to the queue. I do not see any exception either.

I googled around but could not find any examples related to this.

**BasicApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BasicApplication {

    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "helloworld.header.red.q";
    public static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "helloworld.header.x";

    //here the message ==> xchange ==> queue1, queue2
    @Bean
    public List<Object> headerBindings() {
        Queue headerRedQueue = new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, false);
        HeadersExchange headersExchange = new HeadersExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
        return Arrays.asList(headerRedQueue, headersExchange,
                bind(headerRedQueue).to(headersExchange).where("color").matches("red"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicApplication.class, args).close();
    }

}
```

**Producer.java**

```
@Component
public class Producer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();

        //send a message with "color: red" header in the queue, this will show up in the queue
        messageProperties.setHeader("color", "red");
        //MOST LIKELY THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        //BELOW MESSAGE IS NOT LINKED TO ABOVE messageProperties OBJECT
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(EXCHANGE_NAME, "", "Hello World !");

        //send another message with "color: gold" header in the queue, this will NOT show up in the queue
        messageProperties.setHeader("color", "gold");
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(EXCHANGE_NAME, "", "Hello World !");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in that the `MessageProperties` you're creating aren't being used.

Trying building a `Message` that leverages `MessageProperties` with the help of a `MessageConverter`.

Example:

```
MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();
messageProperties.setHeader("color", "red");
MessageConverter messageConverter = new SimpleMessageConverter();
Message message = messageConverter.toMessage("Hello World !", messageProperties);
rabbitTemplate.send("helloworld.header.x", "", message);
```

Comment: You can also use a `convertAndSend()` with a `MessagePostProcessor` callback.

Answer (score 1):

From Java 8 onwards you can also use MessagePostProcessorCallback like this:

```
this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(EXCHANGE_NAME, "", "Hello World !", message -> {
     message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put("color", "gold");
     return message;
    });
```